# Datagrid snapshot of ALL data

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am looking for a way to take a snapshot of ALL of a datagrid's contents to include the data that extends past the bottom of the screen (ie need to scroll the DG down to see more data).

Getting a snapshot of the currently displayed data is simple enough:

```
ImageSnapshot.defaultEncoder = PNGEncoder;
var snap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(myDG);
var imageBytes:ByteArray = snap.data;
```

The only possible solution I have come up with is to take a snapshot, check if the datagrid can be scrolled, scroll to the next position, take another snapshot, and second snapshot to first snapshot, repeat until datagrid is at end.

The problem with that solution is that every new snapshot will have the headers displayed in it. Additionally, the very last snapshot will most likely contain datagrid data from the previous image.

Does anyone have any other thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: what is your purpose to make the snapshot?  Do you want to do something similar to data paging?

Comment: Request from a user to be able to email the contents of the datagrid. After a nap I have a new thought... Why not save it as a CSV and attache it to the mailto instead of a .png??? Would be a whole lot easier. That's the next rabbit hole for me to run down. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to take a snapshot of ALL of a datagrid's
>   contents to include the data that extends past the bottom of the
>   screen (ie need to scroll the DG down to see more data).

In a Flex based list class--including the DataGrid--data does not extend past the bottom of the screen.  Each item from your dataProvider is displayed using an itemRenderer.  itemRenderer will only be created for the number of visual components displayed, not for every item in your dataProvider.

As you scroll through the list, the data property of each itemRenderer is changed; thus changing the display.  Scrolling is really just a simulated change in data.  I call the whole process renderer recycling.

If you want to create a snapshot of a DataGrid with all data displayed you're going to have to create, and render, all the data.  In the MX DataGrid you can do this by adjusting the height so that all items would be visible.  In most spark layouts, there is a property useVirtualLayout which controls this.  I do not know if it can be disabled in the Spark DataGrid, though.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I checked and there is no useVirtualLayout option for the datagrid. Also, shrinking the font down to fit all the contents into one screen is not an option as there is just so much data that when the image would be enlarged to view it the resolution would be terrible. Thanks